# TLS in .NET - Third Party Root CA not recognized as Trusted Root CA

Tags: .net, ssl, https, certificate, tls1.2

I am trying to establish a TLS connection between my .NET application and a website that I have Third-Party Root CA certificate and Intermediate CA certificate installed for:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
var handler = new WebRequestHandler
{
     ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual
};
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(someClientCertificate);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync("https://somewebsite.com").Result;
```

When I try that, I get the following error during server certificate validation:

> (PartialChain) A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted
>   root authority.

When I install the root CA certificate into the Trusted Root CA store the error disappears.

What's the reason for that behavior? From what I've read (see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140211/whats-the-difference-between-trusted-root-certification-authorities-and-thir), I've got an impression that the Third-Party Root CA store is basically just a subset of the Trusted Root CA store so the chain should be built successfully.

Note that installing the root CA certificate to the Trusted Root CA store is not an option for me.

Comment: Did you add it to LocalMachine\ThirdPartyRoot, or was it CurrentUser\ThirdPartyRoot?

Comment: @bartonjs CurrentUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons that I've never understood, the CurrentUser\ThirdPartyRoot store appears to have no function.  At least, it isn't linked in to the chain builder trust decisions in an analagous way to LocalMachine\ThirdPartyRoot.

http://kreelbits.blogspot.com/2014/02/whats-purpose-of-users-third-party-root.html has a bit of a rant-of-self-discovery which shows how the backing implementation of the CurrentUser\Root store is structured differently than LocalMachine\Root.  One infers from this that the "Root" (not "ThirdPartyRoot") store is the only one actually utilized in trust decisions (LM\ThirdPartyRoot gets included via the store link).

Comment: That's so frustrating and not obvious. Could this be a Windows bug and not intended?